# Why is setLandingPageType("billing") working in Sandbox but not in Live-Version in PAYPAL PHP REST API SDK WebProfile

Tags: php, api, rest, paypal, sdk

I have been working on the following workflow using Paypal Payments. 
My intent is to send the Customer to the Guest-Payment-Website. He should not see paypals login-page at first.
This is because many people do not know that they can pay with Creditcard or Bank-Transfer without registering an Account.
I had my whole process tested within the sandbox and it worked. Then I changed to the live-version and `$flowConfig->setLandingPageType("billing");` it is not affecting the landing-page anymore.

Workflow:

- I prepare some `new Webprofile()` which is setting things on paypals payment-approval-site (logo etc., shopname). It is saved once and identified by some string (XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX)
- I prepare a transaction and send it to paypal.
- Then the Customer is sent to the specific payment-approval-site on paypal.com
- the customer should put in his authentication there
- the customer is sent back to my website

To preset visual options I predefine some Webprofile.

```
$flowConfig = new \PayPal\Api\FlowConfig();
$flowConfig->setLandingPageType("billing");

$presentation= new \PayPal\Api\Presentation();
...
$inputFields= new \PayPal\Api\InputFields();
...

$webProfile = new \PayPal\Api\WebProfile();
$webProfile->setName("GuestPaymentProfileNameasdf")
->setFlowConfig($flowConfig)
->setPresentation($presentation)
->setInputFields($inputFields);


$webProfile->create($APIauth)
```

This create-command is giving back some string (XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX) which is saved within paypal to identify this set of options i put into the system.

```
...
$payment->setExperienceProfileId('XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXX'); //profile ID 
...
```

Does anyone know what I could do wrong here? As written, this is totally working within the Sandbox but when I switch to LIVE the customer always is sent to the normal login-page.

Is there some other method to do this?
Did I miss some hint or depreached sign?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working on this and the cause of this behaviour seems to be the limitation of my Paypal-Account within Germany.

At first I was able to buy `as a guest`. Then this option vanished - probably with the expiring of my sandbox-infused cookie. 
So I called the support of Paypal today and asked some specific questions.

I had other expectations about this guest-buy-functionality, because I got used to the unlimited US-Sandbox-Account. My personal mixup might be caused by a possible internal mixup of options / restrictions / limitations when you change from the unlimited sandbox to your restricted live-account.
The Thing is, that I `should not` have seen this `guest-billing-page` within germany - but it worked... once after going live.